# Is there a way to support nested UNC paths for nuget package source?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

In our environment we currently have a nested folder structure that holds our assemblies.
For example: \SERVER\Assemblies\SomeCompany\MyRockinAssembly\v1.0.0.0\MyRockinAssembly.dll

We are looking into creating NuGet Packages for all the good reasons and wanted to store them in the same structure.  So, we would store the nupkg's in the same location where the dll's are: \SERVER\Assemblies\SomeCompany\MyRockinAssembly\v1.0.0.0\MyRockinAssembly.nupkg.

We then planned on adding a local intranet package source and point it at this directory.  However, it doesn't appear that package manager searches nested folders.  If I moved the nupkg up to be only 1 level deep it worked but that kind of messes with our existing standard.

**Is there any way to get nuget to drill down through all sub folders searching for packages?**

Or is this a feature request to their team :)

Answer (score 0):

A NuGet repository is in essence a simple folder containing a set of NuGet packages. The structure you want can not be achieved AFAIK by building such folder tree, unless you register tons of repositories in the clients, each pointing to a specific directory within this tree structure. This might become very inconvenient for consumers of your packages, not to mention unnecessary complicate things further down the road (in automated builds etc).

However, you could play with a package ID structure, e.g.:

```
CompanyName.ProductSuite.Product.Component.1.0.0.nupkg
```

At least your repository will now be sorted, and consumers can filter/search based on this convention.

You could also take a look at [MyGet.org](http://www.myget.org) (NuGet-as-a-Service), create multiple feeds and configure a general feed having your other feeds as underlaying package source. How this works is explained in detail in this blogpost: http://blog.myget.org/post/2012/03/01/Introducing-MyGet-package-source-proxy-(beta).aspx

Comment: From the consumer point I just want them to have the normal single link. I really am looking for the nested structure from an administration/organization of packages point.
I may plan on taking a look at the NuGet Server source code and see if a modification can be done from the hosting standpoint to recursively look at nested folders.  Pushing packages would be a bit more difficult but, we are not planning on pushing via the server but through the back end build process.
I had looked a MyGet but I want to host my own feed internally.